# VBA code to copy cell content to input message (validation)

Tags: excel, vba

I’m not a technical person at all, but I need help on copying cell content to an input message in data validation in Excel. I know there’s a limit to the text string in the input message, happy to trim down the cell content before trying to run the macro.

Comment: If you illustrate your problem with a sample data and desired output mentioning type of validation etc , you may get better response here. Further what effort was put at your end to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Due to luck of explanation, with the below code you can copy cell value to another cell. With code modification you may arise to the desired income.

Try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        str = Application.Clean(Application.Trim(.Range("A1").Value))

        'Copy A1 value to A2
        .Range("A2").Value = str

        'Use A1 value as message on message box
        MsgBox str

        'Use A1 value as data validation on A2
        With Range("A2").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=str
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```